# Howto pass a class name as a variable to another class in ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, parameter-passing

I'm trying to learn to create a multi class program in ruby. I coded an Engine class and some other classes like city, street, etc. and am having problems in passing the class name as a variable to other classes. The code below throws the error: "City.rb:15:in 'intro': undefined local variable or method game' for # (NameError)". I understand the problem in a way, but I don't think that city needs to know anything about 
game object, I think it only has to get it and pass it back. But appearantly I have a misunderstanding about how to pass variables (especially the class name) between classes. What is wrong in my design?

```
#Game.rb
require './City.rb'
class Engine
  def initialize(city_name, street_name, budget)
    @city = City.new(city_name)
    @city.read_name()
    play(@city, :intro, self)
  end

  def play(place, next_step, engine)
    while true
      next_step = place.method(next_step).call(place, next_step, engine)
    end
  end
end

game = Engine.new("Casablanca", "Costanza Boulvard", 200)

#City.rb
class City
  def initialize(city_name)
    @city_name = city_name
  end

  def read_name()
    puts <<-READ_NAME
    You are in a city called "#{@city_name}".
    READ_NAME
  end

  def intro(place, next_step, engine)
    puts "...."
    game.play(@street, :enter, engine)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't see where you are passing class name here.

Comment: Also, fix your naming. Should be `city.rb` and `game.rb` (filenames - snake_case, class names - PascalCase).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried to pass the class name as engine on game.rb#6 as self and on game.rb#9 as variable engine. This is probably where I'm mistaken. Can you give me a solid example of how to pass a class name to another class, totally apart from my example?

Comment: Passing `self` is fine, however within your `intro` method in *City.rb* I think you should be using `engine.play` rather than `game.play`. You are also missing where you assign something to `@street`...

Comment: Do you need to pass an instance of class or class name or class object?

Comment: @Sergio: I plan to pass class object. And I think I do pass it using engine variable and self.

Comment: @Jamie: game.play is fine since it passes the engine object to city. If I change it to engine.play, it complains of undefined local variable or method.

Comment: @barerd: you're passing instance of the class, not the class object. These two are different.

Comment: @Sergio: Sorry for the late response but I googled for that meanwhile, and couldn't find anything useful. So how do I pass the class object?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pass in a class as a parameter as usual:

```
def use_class(myclass)
  x = myclass.new "test"
  x.read_name
end

use_class(City)
# returned -> '    You are in a city called "test".'
```

However, your error is not related to this. Basically, you're trying to use the object `game` within the scope of a class but it doesn't exist there yet.

To pass a reference to the Game instance to the class city, you can do something like:

```
@city = City.new(city_name, self)
```

and modify the constructor of City to

```
  def initialize(city_name, game)
    @city_name = city_name
    @game = game
  end
```

Then, City#intro would have:

```
@game.play(@street, :enter, @game)
```

There probably will be other errors, since `@street` is not defined in City yet, but that's another matter.

Comment: When I look into the problem this way, it sounds very logical and easy. As I mentioned, I have a very steep learning curve for passing parameters, be it for methods or classes. I've read and continue to read tutorials about this but make mistakes every time. Could you mind to point me to a good document about passing parameters or object orientation so that I can find by myself, how @street should be defined in City.

Comment: \@var_name are class variables/members/fields. See how @city_name is intialized. Here's a [tutorial](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/01/22/ruby-class-tutorial/) on classes in ruby.

Comment: I read that tutorial before. Let me put it like this: how can I reference an object of class B inside another object of class A, while neither A or B inherits from each other? When one of them inherits, I can do it. I am still working with the first portion of your code (myclass), and am writing this comment so that it won't be a too late response, sorry.

Comment: Each object has to have a reference of the other object to modify its property. There's no way around it. You could use global variables of the $foo that allow all instance and methods to access the variable. But this is somewhat dangerous.

Comment: So, concerning my code, `@city = City.new()` in game.rb isn't absolutely necessary to refer between each other class, but it just adds a convenience. Thank you very much.